# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'12

Tags: python, database-connection

I am running the following code but expected to get the records from the student table in test database.

Here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector
word = input("Enter a word in English and press Enter: ")
con = mysql.connector.connect(
    user="root", 
    password = "root", 
    host="localhost", 
    database = "test"
)
cursor = con.cursor()
query = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM student")
results = cursor.fetchall()
if results:
    for result in results:
        print(result[1])
else:
    print("We couldn't find any results about that.")
```

And here is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:/python learning/mysqlconnector.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

Comment: try installing this: `pip install mysql-connector-python`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the command

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

in terminal or cmd()